# 'HTML' is not captured ESP32

Tags: arduino, webserver, esp32, arduino-c++

I have a server running on ESP32 using ESPAsyncServer And here

```
server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", String(HTML));
  });
```

this is giving me an error saying

```
error: 'HTML' is not captured
```

i have an HTML string

```
String HTML PROGMEM = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
  HTML += "<html>";
  HTML += "<head>";
  HTML += "<title> Helixis </title>";
  HTML += "<script>";
  HTML += "let gateway = `ws:${window.location.hostname}/ws`";
  HTML += "function initWS(){";
  HTML += "console.log('Connection to WebSocket ... ')";
  HTML += "let ws = new WebSocket(gateway)";
  HTML += "ws.onopen = onOpen";
  HTML += "ws.onclose = onClose";
  HTML += "ws.onmessage = onMessage";
  HTML += "}";
  HTML += "fucntion onOpen(){";
  HTML += "console.log('Succesfully connected to the WebSocket')";
  HTML += "}";
  HTML += "function onClose(){";
  HTML += "console.log('WebSocket connection closed')";
  HTML += "}";
  HTML += "function onMessage(e){";
  HTML += "console.log(e==1 ? `On` : `Off`)";
  HTML += "}";
  HTML += "function onLoad(){";
  HTML += "initWS()";
  HTML += "}";
  HTML += "window.addEventListner('load',onLoad)";
  HTML += "</script>";
  HTML += "</head>";
  HTML += "</html>";
```

and this gives an error ;

any suggestion on what is happening?

Comment: Check the capture clause of your lambda

Comment: It has nothing to do with your problem, but there is a typo in HTML: `HTML += "fucntion onOpen(){";`

Comment: Where is the typo in the code exactly;

Comment: The typo is the writing of 'fucntion', perhaps 'function' instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code :

```
[](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", String(HTML));
  }
```

is a "lambda expression". It won't be evaluated until request->send_P() is called.

It means that HTML won't be defined at that point. In order to make it available for the lamba, it has to be "captured", which means that you must explicitly tell the lambda expression to make it available within `[]`.

As a result, you need to rewrite this code to :

```
[HTML](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", String(HTML));
  }
```

**EDIT** concerning the new error you got :
`no matching function for call to 'AsyncWebServerRequest::send_P(int, const char [11], String)'`

There are 2 `send_P` methods within [ESPAsyncWebServer.h](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/blob/master/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h) :

```
void send_P(int code, const String& contentType, const uint8_t * content, size_t len, AwsTemplateProcessor callback=nullptr);
void send_P(int code, const String& contentType, PGM_P content, AwsTemplateProcessor callback=nullptr);
```

*Side note, P is for sending strings stored in PROGMEM, which is your case.*

Here, you'll need the 2nd one using `PGM_P` to store the `String`.
All that's required is then to convert a `String` into a `PGM_P`.

`PGM_P` is defined into the `avr_pgmspace` namespace as `const char *`. Consequently, you then need to convert your `HTML String` into `const char *`

The lambda finally becomes :

```
[HTML](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", HTML.c_str()));
  }
```

Comment: This gives me an error saying
no matching function for call to 'AsyncWebServerRequest::send_P(int, const char [11], String)'

Comment: Have a look to the documentation for the method your use case required : https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/blob/master/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h , there are 2 send_P available. Each of them is described at the root of this github in the README